"java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
I have a problem, namely the image resource cannot be found
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/GUIForms/JFrame.java to edit this template
 */
package Main;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author USER
 */
public class Menu_utama extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Menu_utama
     */
    public Menu_utama() {
        initComponents();
       this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
       
      execute();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        pn_navbar = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        pn_content = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        pn_utama = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        pn_sidebar = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        pn_menu = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setName("frame"); // NOI18N

        pn_navbar.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 51));
        pn_navbar.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\USER\\OneDrive\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\inventory\\src\\main\\java\\img\\320px-ALFAMART_LOGO_BARU.png")); // NOI18N
        pn_navbar.add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 10, 320, 90));

        pn_content.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        pn_utama.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout pn_utamaLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pn_utama);
        pn_utama.setLayout(pn_utamaLayout);
        pn_utamaLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            pn_utamaLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        pn_utamaLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            pn_utamaLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 510, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout pn_contentLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pn_content);
        pn_content.setLayout(pn_contentLayout);
        pn_contentLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            pn_contentLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(pn_contentLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(pn_utama, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        pn_contentLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            pn_contentLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(pn_contentLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(pn_utama, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pn_sidebar.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        jScrollPane1.setBorder(null);

        pn_menu.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        pn_menu.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(pn_menu, javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(pn_menu);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout pn_sidebarLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pn_sidebar);
        pn_sidebar.setLayout(pn_sidebarLayout);
        pn_sidebarLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            pn_sidebarLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(pn_sidebarLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 242, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        pn_sidebarLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            pn_sidebarLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(pn_sidebar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(pn_content, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addComponent(pn_navbar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 714, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(pn_navbar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 122, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(pn_sidebar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(pn_content, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(730, 652));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu_utama.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu_utama.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu_utama.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Menu_utama.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Menu_utama().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel pn_content;
    private javax.swing.JPanel pn_menu;
    private javax.swing.JPanel pn_navbar;
    private javax.swing.JPanel pn_sidebar;
    private javax.swing.JPanel pn_utama;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private void execute() {
        ImageIcon iconMaster = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/Product.png"));
//        ImageIcon Home = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/Home.png"));
//        ImageIcon User = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/User.png"));
//        ImageIcon Transaction = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/Transaction.png"));
        
        menuItem menuMaster = new menuItem(iconMaster,false,null,"MasterBarang",null);
        addMenu(menuMaster);
    }
//
    private void addMenu (menuItem... menu){
        for(int i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
        pn_menu.add(menu[i]);
        ArrayList<menuItem> subMenu = menu[i].getSubMenu();
        for (menuItem m : subMenu){
            addMenu(m);
        }
    }
    pn_menu.revalidate(); 
    }
}

This My code
and when running the file it will give an error as follows Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
and this is a screenshot of the error

Better to load your files/images as resources:
Netbeans
Eclipse

It appears, from the stack trace [image], that this line of your code is causing the error: ImageIcon iconMaster = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/Product.png")); because method getResource is returning null. Java will search for file Product.png in folder img where the parent folder of img is the same as the parent folder of Main since, according to the code in your question, class Menu_Utama is in package Main. I'm referring to file Menu_utama.class and not Menu_utama.java.

continue how to call the file

Hello @Triahmad Maulana , use ImageIcon iconMaster = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource("src/img/Product.png" )); and probably work.
